# Why this program doesn't go in loop?

Tags: c++, do-while, cin

When I give wrong input like a string "abx", it gives me error message but doesn't go back in loop or ask me to try again. This example is from google c++ course  example 4.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int isecret, iguess, chance;
    srand(time(NULL));
    isecret = rand() %100 + 1;
    cout<<"Enter integers between 1 to 100"<<endl;
    //cout<<isecret<<endl;
    chance = 0;  

    do{
        if (!(cin>>iguess))
        {
            cout<<"please enter integers between 1 to 100"<<endl;
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(10000/'\n');
        }

        else
        {

            if (isecret>iguess)
            {
                cout<<"Your guess is less than the secret"<<endl;
            }
            else if (isecret<iguess)
            {
                cout<<"Your guess is more than the secret"<<endl;
            };
        chance = chance + 1;
        } 
    }
    while(iguess!=isecret);
    cout<<"Congratulation you guess the correct number: "<<isecret<<" in "<<chance<<" chances"<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific with your question?  It's unclear what you're asking.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: so when i run the program, it asks me for an input (which should be an integer). Now suppose if I don't put an integer, then i run into first 'if-conditional', which ask me to enter a valid input. Now here i expect the program to redirect me again to enter new input but instead it stand still. I want to diagonse this.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "stand still" in this context.  But one thing which might help is to add some debugging messages.  For example, put `cout<<"Executing a block which does .... <whatever>"` at various places in your code.  Then, you can see exactly how the program branches.  You can also do this using the debugger.

Comment: Try to initilize `iguess` with 0, like you did with `chance`.

Comment: `cin.ignore(10000/'\n');` Sure?

Answer (score 0):

You missed out a comma. So, replace

```
cin.ignore(10000/'\n');
```

with

```
cin.ignore(10000,'\n');
```

See reference of [cin.ignore()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore)